# In BASH, How do i replace \r from a variable that exist in a file written using HTML <textarea></textarea>

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, archlinux, bash4

How do i replace the \r?

```
#!/bin/bash
...

# setup
if [[ $i =~ $screen ]]; then

    ORIGINAL=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}          # original value is: 3DROTATE\r
    AFTER   =${ORIGINAL/\\r/}            # does not replace \r
    myThirdPartyApplication -o $replvar  # FAILS because of \r

fi
```

Comment: can't have spaces around the `=`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use sed, i.e.,

```
AFTER=`echo $ORIGINAL | sed 's/\\r//g'`
```

Comment: It drops $' in the beginning also. Cool.

Comment: Worked!!!  Just a little improve: spaces are not allowed in value assignation : AFTER=echo...

Answer (score 25):

This should remove the first \r.

```
AFTER="${ORIGINAL/$'\r'/}"
```

If you need to remove all of them use ${ORIGINAL//$'\r'/}

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer, as it avoids the overhead of launching an external program (such as sed or tr).  The $ at the beginning of $'\r' is essential to have the \r converted to a 'carriage return' character in the pattern of things to be replaced.  Maybe it's not obvious, the \r is replaced with nothing (the absence of characters between the last / and }.

Comment: this maybe a top voted answer and works for me too. but there is a problem reported by shellcheck: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC3060

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use 'tr' to delete the character, or replace it with \n or anything else.

```
 ORIGINAL=$(echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} | tr -d '\r')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a literal `^M` character, it has no meaning to bash.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @tharrrk's approach, this parameter substitution also remove the last '\r':

```
AFTER="${ORIGINAL%'\r'}"
```